# Do I need to be experienced with html before building website using ASP.Net with Visual Studio?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

I need to build not very complex website with MySQL database. I am experienced with SQL, .Net languages and a bit of html. I usually use drag and drop to build the website controls and interface.Do I need to learn html first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms you can still do alot of drag and drop for building your web pages but the more you know about HTML the easier it will be to get the results you want.  With ASP.NET MVC it will be even more important to know HTML.

Honestly, if you know sql and a .Net language, then it's likely you can learn HTML pretty quickly.  I'd encourage you to dive and and learn HTML but if you just need to get the project done quickly, you could consider using ASP.NET WebForms (which is an older technology) and it's drag and drop approach will generate alot of the HTML for you.

Comment: Thank you, Can I start the project directly and learn through the progress or I must learn html first because this will be difficult to me?

Comment: The easiest way to learn is often by working through example code.  So there are at least two approach you might find useful: 1) find a tutorial that walks you through the creation of a simple website that has some of the features you eventually want to implement, or 2) Just go ahead and start working on your project and then as you encounter things you don't understand, use google to learn about how that gets coded or what that code means.

Comment: Ok I think I will go the second approach.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Coding will give you the power to understand things more deeply and consistently. You will be able to create more powerful solutions and give more assets to your clients or yourself. So I recommend you to start learning HTML, it will come very useful to you.

On the other hand, using drag and drop to build your sites will do the job, but not in the best or optimal way possible! So go ahead and start learning HTML, there are a lot of sites (look up in google) that can help you to achieve this.

Have a nice day!